# NetBeans 8.2 no me deja programar en java 8 porque?

Tags: java, netbeans

Necesito crear un sistema de ventas en Java 8, tengo NetBeans 8.2 y al crear Java Web con GlassFish o Tomcat solo me da la opción de JavaEE 7 pero no me da opción de Java 8 porque ??
Debo actualizar algo en el ide o en mi pc ?? Tengo Jdk 8 y Jre 8 instalados en mi compu hay que hacer algún cambio ??
Gracias a quien me brinde la información ya busqué en muchos sitios pero no encuentro como agregarlo.

Comment: debes correr todo con JDK 8 para poder usar Java EE 8, según esta información del sitio web de netbeans `JavaEE 8 only runs on JDK 8, not on later releases, and so if you 're doing development with JavaEE 8 it’s best to run NetBeans itself on JDK 8` y tengo instalado netbeans con JDK 8 y todo me funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 2):

**Java EE, ahora llamado Jakarta EE, es la plataforma para el desarrollo de aplicaciones empresariales con Java**. Esta incluye una serie de especificaciones (generalmente) separadas del API estándar que permiten implementar software distribuido con arquitecturas de varias capas. Algunas de las especificaciones que forman parte del Jakarta EE son: JPA, JDBC, JTA, JSP, JSF, EJB.

Lo anterior lo podemos traducir en que: **no es lo mismo Java 8 que Jakarta EE 8**. El primero se refiere a la versión del lenguaje de programación como tal, que define principalmente las características disponobles en el lenguaje (anotaciones, try-with-resources, lambdas, sistema de módulos, etc) y el API estándar (collections, IO, concurrency, etc). El segundo se refiere a la versión de la plataforma empresarial que implica que entre una versión y otra de Jakarta EE (o Java EE) pueden adicionarse o eliminarse especificaciones, o que las versiones de estas pueden variar. Esto lo podemos notar fácilmente viendo que la última versión del lenguaje Java es la 13 y la de Jakarta EE es la 8.

Por lo anterior, que no puedas seleccionar Java EE 8 (o Jakarta EE) quiere decir que esa versión del IDE no tiene soporte para las especificaciones (o las versiones de estas) disponibles en Jakarta EE 8 y nunca que no puedas programar con la versión 8 del leguaje.

**La primera versión de NetBeans compatible con Jakarta EE 8 es la 11.1.**

Comment: https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/java_ee-7-fr-eval-spec/JavaEE_Platform_Spec.pdf?AuthParam=1580104880_ce1297c876892d3567200ab0f148516a dice Java 7+, por lo que es posible, pero no es recomendado, ver por ejemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845699/is-it-discouraged-using-java-8-parallel-streams-inside-a-java-ee-container

Comment: @RuslanLópez si lees bien lo que se comenta es que el uso de Parallel Streams en un contexto de Java EE no aportaría muchos beneficios, pero Java 8 es muchísimo más que Parallel Streams.